# focus textfield if javascript validation failed

Tags: javascript, focus

I've this code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function validate(){
                var name=document.frm.name.value;
                if(name.indexOf("A")==0){
                    alert(name);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="frm" action="test.php">
            Enter name:<input type="text" name="name" onblur="validate()"/>
            Enter e-Mail:<input type="text" name="email" onblur=""/>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

In above code, I'd tried to validate textfields when they lose focus. The script working fine if the name starts with `A`. But I want if the user enter different name which doesn't start with `A` it will return the focus to the textfield `name`. For that I'd written this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var name = document.frm.name.value;
    if(name.indexOf("A") == 0){
        alert(name);
    }else{
        document.frm.name.focus();
    }
</script>
```

then it doesn't works.

Anybody could help with that what should I do to request focus of textfield `name`?
I've only a little knowledge of `javascript`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give an `id` for you form and refer it with `document.getElementById('form_id')`. Use of `name` attribute in this context has been deprecated over a decade ago. Also `name` for `input` should be something else than `"name"`, rather use `username` or sth.

**HTML**:

```
<form id="frm" action="test.php">
    Enter name:<input type="text" name="username" id="username" onblur="validate()"/>
    Enter e-Mail:<input type="text" name="email" id="email" onblur=""/>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
function validate(){
    var form = document.getElementById('frm');
    if (form.username.value.indexOf("A") === 0) {
        alert(name);
    } else {
        form.username.focus();
    }
}
```

Instead of retrieving the `id` of the `form`, you can also pass the `form` to `validate()` as an argument: `onblur="validate(this);"`. Then use that argument as a `form` in the eventhandler:

```
function validate(form){
    if (form.username.value.indexOf("A") === 0) {
        alert(name);
    } else {
        form.username.focus();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Focus doesn't seem to work without a delay, you can try this (the `input`has an `id="username"`):

```
function focusTo (elm) {
    elm.focus();
    return;
}

function validate(){
    var form = document.getElementById('frm');
    if (form.username.value.indexOf("A") === 0) {
        alert(name);
    } else {
        alert('error');
        setTimeout(function () {focusTo(form.username);}, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: what if the user doesn't enter a name starting with `A`? how would i focus that textfield?

Comment: can I pass the reference of textfield like this: `onBlur="validate(this.username)"`?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal Yes, that's valid too.

Comment: Why you have used `===` instead of `==`?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal I've just used to use [strict operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) when comparing. Actually it doesn't matter here, since `indexOf()` will always return a number.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24820/discussion-between-mohammad-faisal-and-teemu)

Answer (score 2):

modifiy your script like this

```
   <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function validate(){
                var name=document.frm.name.value;
                if(name.indexOf("A")==0){
                    alert(name);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body >
        <form id="frm" action="test.php">
            Enter name:<input type="text" name="username" onblur="validate()"/>
            Enter e-Mail:<input type="text" name="email" onblur=""/>
            <input type="submit" onclick="check()"/>
        </form>
        <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
        <!--
        function validate()
        {
            var name = document.getElementById('frm').username.value;
            if(name.indexOf("A") == 0){
                alert(name);
                        document.getElementById('frm').email.focus();
             }else{
                document.getElementById('frm').username.focus();
            }
        }
        function check()
        {
            var name = document.getElementById('frm').username.value;
            if(name.indexOf("A") == 0){
             }else{
                alert("Please enter a name starting with 'A'");
                     document.getElementById('frm').username.focus();
            }
        }
        //-->
        </SCRIPT>
    </body>
</html>
```

You want to execute function `validate()` on event `onblur`. in the script you have written the code for focusing, but not added it in a function.

Comment: Not working? Without adding a word starting with 'A' focus is on name text field. can you explain not working?

Comment: try

<input type="text" name="name" onblur="validate"/>
instead of
<input type="text" name="name" onblur="validate()"/>

Answer (score 0):

try this `document.frm.username.focus();` . i hope it will work.